# SignalR Client Hub Proxy is Undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I was following [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host) tutorial. On client side, in a simple html page, I get undefined for the client hub proxy from SignalR; What am I missing?

This links work properly (client is another asp.net mvc project at the same solution):

```
http://localhost:28538/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js
http://localhost:28538/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
http://127.0.0.1:9077/signalr/hubs
http://127.0.0.1:9077/signalr/js
```

My Hub class:

```
class AlohaHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Startup class (which will be passed to `WebApp.Start`):

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

The main part of the app (a windows service, but that's irrelevant):

```
class MyAppSvc : WinSvc.ISvc
{
    IDisposable _app;
    string _url = "http://127.0.0.1:9077";

    public void OnShutdown()
    {
        _app.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _app = Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<MyApp.SigR.Startup>(_url);
    }

    public void OnStop()
    {
        _app.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The actual html page; the client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SigR Sample</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:9077/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //Set the hubs URL for the connection
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://127.0.0.1:9077/signalr";

            $.connection.hub.logging = true;

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.alohaHub;
            alert(chat);
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is down to cross-domain issues... have you hosting SignalR on the same localhost port?

Comment: No; the ports are different. So I've added `<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>` to web.config; yet no success (or I am uninformed on this topic).

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable CORS support on your server for cross domain to work (I'll also list how to enable jsonp).

**To Enable Cors:**

1. Install Microsoft ASP.NET Cross-Origin Support via nuget (Microsoft.Owin.Cors)
2. Add this to your startup file (before your map signalr call):

:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); // You can modify the CorsOptions
```

**To Enable JSONP:**

Modify your "MapSignalR" in your startup file via:

```
app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
{
    EnableJSONP = true
});
```

To do both together you can do:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
    .MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
    {
        EnableJSONP = true
    });
```

Keep in mind enabling these cross domain features on your SignalR server exposes it to potential security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I had to install Microsoft.Owin.Cors, not Microsoft.AspNet.Cors (I think this is a SignalR 2.x thing)